# Sync two remote branches

Tags: git

I am new to git. Need help.
We have two remote branches- mainline and one for my project (project).
Now, I have been pushing all my changes to the project branch.
But someone recently made changes to mainline branch without my knowledge.
I was earlier thinking to merge my remote branch with the mainline branch once I am done with pushing all my changes to the project branch.

But, now I first have to update the project branch with changes in mainline
How can we sync two remote branches?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all fetch the changes made to `mainline` branch, merge them locally to `project` branch (resolve conflicts if any) then push `project` branch to `<remote>` (most likey 'origin') and then merge it to `mainline` branch.

1. Fetch all change from remote `git fetch <remote>`
2. Then `git merge <remote>/mainline` to merge is locally.

Make sure you do this while you are on `project` branch.
Also you can combine both of the above and use `git pull <remote> mainline`.